# How to get the regularity of the pde similar to biharmonic equation on convex polyhedroid?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, elliptic-operators

I'v seen the regularity results for biharmonic equation:
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{l}
\Delta^2 u=f, \quad \text { in } \Omega, \\
\left.u\right|_{\partial \Omega}=\left.\frac{\partial u}{\partial \boldsymbol{\nu}}\right|_{\partial \Omega}=0 .
\end{array}\right.
$$
If $\Omega$ is a convex polyhedroid in $\mathbb{R}^2$, then for any $f\in H^{-1}(\Omega)$, the solution of the equation is in $H^3(\Omega) $ and $\|u\|_{3,\Omega} \leqslant C\|f\|_{-1,\Omega}$.

I hope to consider the elliptic equation like
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{l}
\Delta( \beta(x,y) \Delta u)=f, \quad \text { in } \Omega, \\
\left.u\right|_{\partial \Omega}=\left.\frac{\partial u}{\partial \boldsymbol{\nu}}\right|_{\partial \Omega}=0 .
\end{array}\right.
$$
Still suppose that $\Omega$ is a convex polyhedroid in $\mathbb{R}^2$, and assume that $\beta\geq \beta_{1}\geq 0$, and $\beta \in C^{\infty}$, can I prove that $\|u\|_{3,\Omega} \leqslant C\|f\|_{-1,\Omega}$?

Comment: What is a polyhedroid? In $\mathbb{R}^2$, are they not just polygons? And in higher dimensions, are they the same thing as polyhedra (sometimes called polytopes)?

Comment: Yes , it's polygon.

Comment: Yes, I think he means polytope.

Comment: Without knowing anything about biharmonic equations, my first instinct is to try to mimic your favorite proof of elliptic regularity. For example, there's a pretty conceptual proof that uses wavefront sets. I vaguely suspect something along those lines might work, because it's not obvious to me where in such a proof you critically use that the equation is second order.

Comment: Is it possible to finish the proof just by the regularity of Laplace equation and the biharmonic equation? Here the $\beta$ can be smooth enough.